# Custom values in sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, doctrine, widget

I have a *User* model with *name* and *surname* columns. I'm trying to create a selector in a form using `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice`, which by default only display the *name* values.

How can I modify the widget to display *both the name and the surname*? I know you can pass a query option when initializing the widget, but I cannot make it work:

```
$this->setWidget('user_id', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
    'model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('User'),
    'query' => Doctrine_Query::create()->select('u.name, u.surname')->from('User u'),
    'add_empty' => false)
));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`method`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice) option and create a `public function` of whatever method name that you want in your `User` model. An example might be:

```
$this->setWidget('user_id', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
    'model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('User'),
    'method' => 'getFullName',
    'add_empty' => false)
));
```

And then in your lib/model/Doctrine/User.class.php file

```
public function getFullName() {
    return "{$this->getName()} {$this->getSurname()}";
}
```

Comment: or you can just define __toString method in User model, then you don't have to change the widget at all.